# DynamoDB Connection Biulding using AWS Java SDK by getting Keys from the user at runtime

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to connect to DynamoDB by getting AccessID and SecretKey from the user. AmazonDynamoDBClient has been depreciated and the replacement don't allow me to get credentials from the user and make a connection to DynamoDB. Here is my code snippet. The solution I'm getting is to keep the keys in a local file. I don't need this.

```
        DynamoDB dynamoDB = null;

    try {
        System.out.println(1);
        BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials(upDoc.getAccID(), upDoc.getAccKey());
        System.out.println(2);
        //AmazonDynamoDBClient is depreciated  
        AmazonDynamoDBClient client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(awsCreds).withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_2);
        System.out.println(3);
        dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(client);
        writer.append("Access Granted By AWS DynamoDB \n");
    }catch(AmazonDynamoDBException e) {
        writer.append("Access Denied By AWS DynamoDB \n");
        writer.close();
        return "Error occured. Kindly check logs to get the actual cause!";         
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder`

```
BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials(upDoc.getAccID(), upDoc.getAccKey());
AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_2).withCredentials(awsCreds).build();
```

Comment: .withCredentials() takes AWSCredentialsProvider, not the BasicAWSCredentials :-(

Comment: AWSCredentialsprovider is an interface and BasicAWSCredentials is an implementation of that interface. They are the same thing.